# I can't start a session after powering down in middle of a Ubuntu 16.04 Upgrade

Tags: system-installation

So basically I was updating Ubuntu to 16.04 and since I need to change the fan, the laptop is turning off often. As a result, the computer shut down before finish the updating.

Now I turn on my computer and I just can see random codes displaying in the screen repeatedly without starting session.

Do you know guy how I access to the OS??

I appreciate any help!!! Thank you

Comment: I don't know what "random codes" means. Perhaps a link to a screenshot uploaded to imgur.com or similar would help us to ascertain what your problem might be.

Comment: The first thing to do is clean out all the lint from your fan exhaust port! Search on youtube for your laptop make and how to clean fan. New fans can be purchased for $12 to $20 on ebay. I've never tried it but theoretically you could put your vacuum cleaner wand on the fan exhaust port to cool the CPU during the next upgrade. Also download temperature indicators which will warn you when shut down will occur due to critical heat (usually around 100 degrees C).

Comment: Yes even if you get the upgrade done the overheating will note make it that useful.

Comment: Do **not** **not** **not** use a vacuum cleaner on your fan's exhaust port while it's running, especially if it is a laptop.  This will pull a comparatively massive volume of air through a tiny fan and can significantly overspeed it, damaging it physically and possibly even electrically.  An electric motor is also a generator, and running it that fast could send quite a voltage into your laptop motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

First I suggest fixing whatever hardware issue caused the computer to shut down before.  If it's a clogged fan then clean it out.  **Do not attempt to repair your Ubuntu installation before you do this.**  You already have a damaged installation, if a shutdown occurs during repair it may render the system unrepairable (if it isn't already)

I would then suggest trying to boot your computer from an external Ubuntu DVD of the same version that your system was before the attempted update.  Once this is done, the first thing you need to then do is make a backup image of your hard drive.  It's important when trying to repair a broken system to make a baseline you can go back to in case repairs do not go well.

Then, finally, to make the repairs you can mount the affected partition, chroot to it, and then see if apt can finish the upgrade.

Here is step by step what I would do.  In this I'm assuming you know enough about your computer to know (or find out) what partition(s) Linux is on and have a basic understanding of tools like apt and dd.  If this isn't the case, then attempting this may be beyond your current knowledge and it may be beneficial to get outside help.  There are too many variables to try and give every command you should do to fix things explicitly.

Step by step, I would:

1. Fix the hardware problem.  If whatever caused the shutdown in the first place can't be fixed, attempting to repair the installation is more dangerous than leaving it in it's current state of brokenness.
2. Download and burn a live DVD of the same version of Ubuntu you were using before the attempted upgrade.
3. Boot off that DVD and make an image of your hard drive.  As stated above, it's important to have a baseline you can go back to if anything fails.  You will need an external drive large enough to hold a compressed image of your drive.  If you don't have one, then this is great incentive to get one.  If your hard drive is /dev/sda, then once you are booted into the live DVD and have a terminal you can:

   ```
   $ sudo dd if=/dev/sda bs=1024k | gzip -c > sda.img.gz
   ```

   Adjust as needed for what device your hard drive is.
4. Once you have a backup, try and mount your Linux installation so that it can be chroot'ed into.  Some Linux installations have separate partitions for /boot, /home, etc.  If you do then they all need to be mounted.  For example, if /boot is /dev/sda1 and root is /dev/sda2, then:

   ```
   $ sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
   $ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot
   $ sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
   $ sudo chroot /mnt
   # mount -t proc proc /proc
   # mount -t sysfs sys /sys
   # mount -t devpts devpts /dev/pts
   ```

   Again, adjust for the particulars of your installation.  Linux may be on a different partition.  There may be no /boot.  There may be a separate /home partition.  Whatever the case is, mount root under /mnt, then everything else as /mnt/whatever until you chroot.
5. Once you are chroot'ed into your Linux partition, you are essentially live on your old installation.  The following may be enough to get you back up and running:

   ```
   $ update-initramfs -k all -c
   $ update-grub
   ```

   That will update the boot system and may be enough to get you bootable again.  However, you still want to go on to
6. Use dpkg to reconfigure your installed packages and apt to complete the upgrade:

   ```
   $ dpkg --configure -a
   $ apt update
   $ apt upgrade
   ```

   This will have dpkg try and fix whatever is currently broken in your packages, then gets apt to update your repositories and then finish the upgrade.

The above is, I think, your best bet for getting up and running in a partially automatic way.  Usually apt is pretty good at fixing anything it's left undone if it's been interrupted before.  If this doesn't work, then your system is likely beyond the means of being helped by a person answering a question here, and will need the personal attention of someone with a deeper knowledge of Linux in general and Debian-esque distributions in particular.